# How to mount a device in ttyUSB0?

Tags: drivers, usb, mount

I'm trying to mount a USB internet dongle (data card).

The output of `dmesg` is:

```
[20200.396232] option 2-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[20200.396448] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[20200.396681] option 2-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[20200.396891] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[20200.397090] option 2-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[20200.397270] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[20200.397674] scsi15 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.4
[20201.393856] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ZTE      USB Storage FFFE 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[20201.394677] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[20201.396164] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

How do I mount this so that I can run an installation script present in it?

Answer (score 0):

From the last 2 lines we can assume your dongle mass storage device is `sdb`.

This mean the device is present on `/dev/sdb`.

You can mount the device to access it by doing `mount /dev/sdb /your/folder`.

`ls /your/folder` to see the content of the freshly mounted storage, then identify the installation script and run it `/your/folder/installation_script_name`.